# navigating to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I am facing some issues with navigation back to previous page.
What I am trying to do is in a cancel-button click I am calling a function where I am using `history.back();` which is working fine. The problem is that the same page is having some validation so when I am clicking the cancel-button it is checking all the fields and then it is navigating back.

I also used `history.go(-1)` getting same issue.
I even tried `app.navigate("details/");` which is working fine but it is coming in loop. For example: if I am navigating back to page 2 from page 3 its working but when I am trying to navigate from page 2 to page 1 its coming back to page 3.

Can someone please help me figure this out.

Comment: What other code is on the cancel button, and what HTML do you use to display this cancel button?

Comment: <div class="btn-cancel" data-bind="dxButton: {text: 'Cancel', onClick: handlecancel}"></div>

Comment: function handlecancel() {        
        //history.go(-1);
        //history.back();
        //Mobile.app.navigate("details/");
        
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

Adapted to http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/SPA_Framework/Navigation_and_Routing/?version=15_2 you can also navigate back like this:

```
Application1.app.navigate('View1', { root: true });
// or
Application1.app.navigate('View1', { target: 'current' });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried both the ways the first way is making my previous view as a root page from where I am not able to navigate initial page.           and second way also didn't works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [back method](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/SPA_Framework/HtmlApplication/Methods/?version=15_2#back).

```
Application1.app.back();
```